# File do not exist Error - Android

Tags: android, file-upload

I have this code that allows me to select a file and upload it to a server.
Whenever I test it, it always  says "File do not exist", I test it with different file explorer, but it's always the same message.
This is UploadFilesToServer.java

```
package com.example.hp.test;

/**
 * Created by Haroun SMIDA on 8/8/2015.
 */

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.hp.test.app.AppConfig;

public class UploadFilesToServer extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView uploadStatus;
    private Button btnUploadFile;
    private Button btnSelectFIle;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;

    private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;

    /**
     * *******  File Path ************
     */
    private String uploadFilePath = null;
    private String uploadFileName = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploadfile);

        btnUploadFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUploadFile);
        btnUploadFile.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnSelectFIle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectFile);
        btnSelectFIle.setOnClickListener(this);

        uploadStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uploadStatus);


        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = AppConfig.URL_UPLOAD;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnSelectFile:
                selectFile();

                break;
            case R.id.btnUploadFile:
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadFilesToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                uploadStatus.setText("uploading started.....");
                            }
                        });
                        Log.i("File Path ", uploadFilePath);
                        Log.i("File Name ", uploadFileName);
                        uploadFile(uploadFilePath);

                    }
                }).start();
                ;
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

    }


    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        Log.i("File Uri ", sourceFileUri);
        Log.i("File ", sourceFile.toString());

        if (!sourceFile.exists()) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                    + uploadFilePath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    uploadStatus.setText("Source File not exist :"
                            + uploadFilePath);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=" + fileName + "" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                    + " http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                    + uploadFileName;

                            uploadStatus.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadFilesToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        uploadStatus.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(UploadFilesToServer.this, "MalformedURLException",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        uploadStatus.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(UploadFilesToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }

    private void selectFile() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        uploadStatus.setText("Uploading file path :- '" + uploadFilePath+ "'");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
                Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                String uriString = selectedFileUri.toString();
                File fileToUpload = new File(uriString);
                uploadFilePath = fileToUpload.getAbsolutePath();

                if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedFileUri, null, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            uploadFileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                    uploadFileName = fileToUpload.getName();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What is the right method that allows me to get the right path for the selected file?

Comment: .'Whenever I test it, it always says "File do not exist",'. But that is not all. It tells the path too. What exactly is the path?

Comment: 'test it with different file explorer,'. Where and how are you using file explorers?

Comment: 1- This is the path it shows to me : "file:/storage/sdcard0/Test/test.txt".

Comment: 'uploadStatus.setText("Uploading file path :- '" + uploadFilePath+ "'");'. That code should not be in selectFile().

Comment: 2- I am letting the android system choose the right application for select file. So When I press the Select Button, a Dialog popups and provide me with list of the available file explorers

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how the path should look like in order the complete the process of uploading

Comment: 'file:/storage/sdcard0/Test/test.txt". No. If then it will show "file:///storage/sdcard0/Test/test.txt"   Remove 'file://' from it so the path starts with /storage...

Comment: You mean the right path should be something like "/storage/sdcard0/Test/test.txt" ?

Comment: Yes indeed. That is a file system path suitable for File and FileInputStream classes.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'll try it now